# How to know in which system test failed in parallel test execution?

Tags: selenium, testng, selenium-grid, parallel-testing

I'm running 11 test scenarios on 3 different system all together parallely.

S1: Win7 Firefox46.0
S2: Win10 Chrome58.0
S3: Mac Safari9.0

After completion I can see the test failure in TestNG report but I can't track in which system the scenario is failed.

Is there any way so that I can track in which system or environment test failed.

Comment: Can you consider showing us your work please? Do update us the `testng.xml` in the question area for further analysis. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How do yo execute the test cases? Do you do it in your build with CI-System, IDE?

On the selenium website https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2 is described how to surrender capabilities on the grid. You could deliver them as String variables and looking for their values in case of failing.

Maybe this could help you?

Answer (score 0):

Using TestNG it can be very easy: Just put the browser name as a parameter into a data provider and print it in your stacktrace. It can be shortened like: "ch" for Chrome or "ff" for Firefox.

A control variable like can be useful for you if you decide to run a test case in another browser tommorow.